# Mapping Model To ViewModel Inside Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am trying to convert a model into a viewmodel inside my controller, I need to use the data inside of a @Html.DropdownListFor(). My view is using the viewmodel so I need to map all of the model data to this viewmodel before hand

**Model** **StandardSubjectAreaTierOne**:

```
public class StandardSubjectAreaTierOne
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }
}
```

**Model** **Sector**:

```
public class Sector
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ApprenticeshipOccupationId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
}
```

**Model** **Standard**:

```
public class Standard
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ApprenticeshipSectorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ApprenticeshipLevel ApprenticeshipLevel { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel** **StandardViewModel**:

```
public class StandardViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ApprenticeshipSectorId { get; set; }

    public SelectList ApprenticeshipSectors { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SelectList ApprenticeshipLevels { get; set; }

    public string ApprenticeshipLevel { get; set; }
}
```

I am not entirely sure whether or not I am suppose to use SelectList for my dropdownlistfor either.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateStandard()
{
    var response = _adminMediator.GetStandard();

    return View(response.ViewModel);
}
```

_adminMediator.GetStandard returns

```
MediatorResponse<List<StandardSubjectAreaTierOne>>
```

response needs to be converted into the viewmodel because I am getting an error saying StandardSubjectAreaTierOne cannot be converted to StandardViewModel

**View**:

```
@model SFA.Apprenticeships.Web.Raa.Common.ViewModels.Admin.StandardViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApprenticeshipLevel, Model.ApprenticeshipLevels)
```

---

**New Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateStandard()
{
    var response = _adminMediator.GetStandard();

    var test = response.ViewModel.SelectMany(
                r =>
                    r.Sectors.SelectMany(
                        ss =>
                            ss.Standards.Select(
                                s =>
                                    new StandardViewModel()
                                    {
                                        ApprenticeshipLevel = s.ApprenticeshipLevel,
                                        ApprenticeshipSectorId = ss.Id,
                                    }))).ToList();

    return View(test);
}
```

I also changed the model in the view to

```
List<SFA.Apprenticeships.Web.Raa.Common.ViewModels.Admin.StandardViewModel>
```

Now I am just having an issue with my dropdownlistfor when I run the application

Comment: What type does `_adminMediator.GetStandard()` return? And what is typeof property `ViewModel`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated it, it says just below the controller info. ViewModel is type List<StandardSubjectAreaTierOne>

Comment: `StandardViewModel` appears to be related to `Standard` based on the properties. It does not appear to have any relationship to `StandardSubjectAreaTierOne` (let alone a collection of it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke it doesn't have a relation to StandardSubjectAreaTierOne but the method which collects all the data is of this type since it is used somewhere else. This method collects all the data I need so I am not going to create another method when I already have one.

Comment: But your view expects a single `StandardViewModel` - a `List<StandardSubjectAreaTierOne>` is a collection and each `StandardSubjectAreaTierOne` contains a collection of `Sector` which contains a collection of `Standard` - which `Standard` in which `Sector` in which `StandardSubjectAreaTierOne` do you want to edit?. And where does the collection of `ApprenticeshipLevels` come from?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I make an update of what I have done so far and could you let me know if im on the right track, I think I am im just getting an error with my dropdownlistfor now

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127039/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-luke-rayner).